# Bloom Filter class to include in my OMNET++ project

Tags: omnet++, bloom-filter

I'm doing a project using OMNET++. All I need is a decent bloom filter class(Hash functions that can take in a string and simple control functions: add/reset/check), so I can create an object of it and use it in my network.
I tried creating one myself but the hash function part gave me trouble. I'm operating my project simulation on a simple macbook pro.
Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically use any available bloom-filter implementation for C++, e.g., https://code.google.com/p/bloom/